# Delete all rows from a mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to delete all the records from a MySQL table (46 records).
The code I have tried. Any suitable answer?

```
Session hs = connection.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria cr = hs.createCriteria(Bookmark.class);
        Bookmark b;
        List<Bookmark> li = cr.list();
        for (Bookmark s : li) {
            b = new Bookmark();
            b.setId(s.getId());

            Transaction tr = hs.beginTransaction();
            hs.delete(b);
            tr.commit();
            hs.flush();
            hs.close();
        }
```

Error

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [mypojos.Bookmark#7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant delete objects like that. You would first have to get the object from db and then you can delete using hs.delete(b); this is usually used when you have to cascade changes to associated objects.

Best approach in this case is to use HQL query something like this.

```
String stringQuery = "DELETE FROM tablename";
Query query = session.createQuery(stringQuery);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery(stringQuery); Thank you Faizan.